# Interrupt a method C#

Tags: c#, return, interrupt

is there a way in C# to Interrupt a Method by a condition, without checking the condition manuelly after every row?

manuelly would look like this:

```
function(){
i++;
condition okay?;
i = i + 2;
condition okay?;
i = i + 3;
condition okay?;
.....
}
```

Comment: j=1; while(condition ok) {i+=j; j++;}

Comment: `for (int j = 0; condition okay; i += ++j) {...}`

Comment: How is `condition` modified?

Comment: If you are asking how you can stop processing a method that is currently executing, you would want to pass in a CancellationToken and monitor its IsCancellationRequested property.

Comment: I think this should be the right way @RickDavin but I dont know how to implement it. Do you have a example for me?

Comment: Even if you pass in a CancellationToken, you would need to sprinkle checks regarding it throughout your code. The answer to your question, is there a way to do this without sprinkling checks throughout your code, and the answer is no. None that is good.

Answer (score 0):

C# has its own mechanism to cancel a long running process: the [CancellationToken structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=net-5.0).  The provided link has an example.  Plus you can search on your own for ".net cancellationtoken".

The key property to monitor is the Boolean [IsCancellationRequested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.iscancellationrequested?view=net-5.0).  That look also has a simple example.

Do understand that your long running method needs to check this flag to decide what to do.  You may decide to abruptly cancel with the [ThrowIfCancellationRequested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested?view=net-5.0) method.  But if you have disposable objects open, you will want to gracefully cancel the method.

Another good link is: [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads)

It explains the difference between a [CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=net-5.0) and a `CancellationToken`.  Your long running method should only accept a `CancellationToken`.  Your calling method may have a `CancellationTokenSource` and you would call its [Cancel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancel?view=net-5.0) method or [CancelAfter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancelafter?view=net-5.0) method to communicate to the passed token that you desire to cancel.

The `CancelAfter` method is a nice way to put a time limit on the long running method.

Many people will use a nullable `CancellationToken` in their method signature.
Example: `LongRunningMethod(CancellationToken? token = null)`.  While this works, I think it is better to use `LongRunningMethod(CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken)`, which returns an empty [CancellationToken.None](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.none?view=net-5.0).